# NOT strip debug symbols ndk-build

Tags: android-ndk

Seems like ndk-build strips debug symbols when it copies .so from obj to lib folder. Is there a way to tell ndk-build not to strip the debug symbols?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In your Android.mk you could override `cmd-strip` to do what you want, e.g. nothing:

```
# Don't strip debug builds
ifeq ($(APP_OPTIM),debug)
    cmd-strip := 
endif
```

Comment: I would instead check the value of NDK_DEBUG, eg: `ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)`

Comment: Thanks so much! IMHO, there is no reason to strip the debug build. I don't understand the motivation behind this.

Comment: Possible reasoning behind this is that devices can be low on memory and apk can be huge (in my case it is apk with C++ tests). BTW, putting this in Application.mk doesn't work, Android.mk only.

Comment: Finally after many answers in SO, this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Adding [this](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk#app_strip_mode) to `Application.mk` solved it for me:

```
APP_STRIP_MODE := none
```

So, taking suggestions from @Michael and @gmetal:

```
ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
  APP_STRIP_MODE := none
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/android/ndk/wiki/Changelog-r18-beta2

- Use `APP_STRIP_MODE` in `Application.mk` of your NDK application

```
ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
  APP_STRIP_MODE := none
endif
```

- OR `LOCAL_STRIP_MODE` in `Android.mk` of your NDK module

```
ifeq ($(NDK_DEBUG),1)
  LOCAL_STRIP_MODE := none
endif
```