# How to avoid stripping for native code symbols for android app

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, stripping

I'm getting `sigsegv 11` in native code and i need to avoid stripping to understand what's wrong. The app uses library (aar) and i was able to avoid stripping for the aar with 'cmd-strip' [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37575043/not-strip-debug-symbols-ndk-build). But in the apk stripped version of `.so` is used anyway so the app strips the symbols, probably while `transformNative_libsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug` gradle task. Any change to avoid it?

PS. Found [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40036945/android-studio-2-2-compress-all-so-files-in-built-apk) on SO but it's a bit different (using aar here with not stripped symbols in my case).

Comment: IMO, you should think twice if you really need to ship non-stripped binaries with your APK. Cons are extremely increased size of shared libraries and poor reverse engineering protection. If you just want to find non-stripped binaries somewhere - look under `obj/local/`. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40278937/2878070) for details.

Comment: it's just to fix the issue, not for distribution

Comment: If so - `ndk-build` creates non-stripped files along with stripped ones already. See my previous comment.

Comment: they are not stripped when building aar, but ARE stripped when building app. see my question

Answer (score 58, accepted):

There's an undocumented method 'doNotStrip' in packagingOptions, just add following lines in your build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
    doNotStrip "*/arm64-v8a/*.so"
    doNotStrip "*/armeabi-v7a/*.so"
    doNotStrip "*/x86/*.so"
    doNotStrip "*/x86_64/*.so"
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this. It will make your APK huge and it's unnecessary. See my answer on how to symbolize your stack traces.

Comment: it's needed only because some .so files are encrypted and would be broken if stripped.

Comment: fwiw, i'm having the exact opposite issue with Android Studio 3.1/3.2 and gradle 4.4. It no longer strips debug symbols and I can't find a way to force stripping! not LOL.

Comment: @3c71: That's a bug that was fixed in 3.2 canary 4: https://issuetracker.google.com/72752164

Comment: @DanAlbert I actually opened that issue ;)

Comment: Heh, didn't notice the date. Thanks for reporting the issue!

Comment: You are amazing! This also fix the same issue using NDK 17.

Comment: Well, this **is** required when profiling app with simpleperf, as described [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/simpleperf/+/ndk-r14-beta1/README.md), because without this symbols are missing in profile report. Also, when using Android Studio's native profiler, it does not display symbols **even** if native libraries are not stripped, meaning that it does not use the `simpleperf` internally...

Comment: What's the equivalent of doNotStrip in Apache Ant?

Answer (score 8):

Fortunately you don't actually need to keep the symbols in the app. The NDK ships a tool called `ndk-stack` (it's in the root of the NDK) that can symbolize a stack trace for you: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/ndk-stack.html

Comment: It seems doNotStrip is needed to see symbols in logcat in case of crash, and to perform debuging with lldb in Android Studio

Comment: The former is handled by ndk-stack, and the latter is not true. If you're seeing the latter it's a bug and you should file it.

Comment: We couldn't find a way to use any sort of debugging with lldb without doNotStrip. No symbol names in the debug stack, no local variable names, no breakpoints etc (with NDK 21 and Android Studio beta). Where to report a bug (NDK or Android Studio) ? Also using ndk-stack is very cumbersome compared to simply seeing the backtrace in the logcat. Maybe Android Studio can automate this ? Thanks

Comment: It would be an Android Studio bug. Follow https://source.android.com/setup/contribute/report-bugs

Comment: "Also using ndk-stack is very cumbersome compared to simply seeing the backtrace in the logcat. Maybe Android Studio can automate this ?" Yeah, that would be good. If you file the FR I can help find an owner for it.

Comment: Created https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144151370 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/144150380