# Native libs issue starting process command

Tags: java, android, sdk, android-ndk

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.

> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\mips64el-linux-android-strip''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem and the solution was to increase the maximum heap size for both Gradle and Android Studio. Try to put this in your `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms1548m -Xmx6g
```

Also to increase the maximum heap size of Android Studio follow the instructions [here.](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#adjusting_heap_size)

If it doesn't help either you can tell gradle [not to strip the debug symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42269046/4432988) at all, but I wouldn't advise doing that.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and my solution was to uninstall the ndk in SDK Tools and it worked.
Maybe the project doesn't need a ndk.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, all I did is run the command in Terminal

**rm -rf ~/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle**