# The Gradle Sync Failed for my Android Studio Project : Execution failed for task

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, build.gradle

I get this message error when i tried to run app.

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>   * What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':synchronizationservice:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug'.
>
> A problem occurred starting process 'command 'D:\Workspace_Android_Studio\Sdk\ndk-bundle\toolchains\mips64el-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\mips64el-linux-android-strip''

After many research, i find a problem about sdk. But i can't change the value of

> uses-sdk android target sdk version

The value provided by gradle.

I supposed the problem is about NDK, i want delete it but i can't.
I see this message in the log :

> Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2,

Comment: Possible dublicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50392957/native-libs-issue-starting-process-command/50400017#50400017

Comment: Ty man, I find the solution by myself. It was the same solution. ( For information i delete the folder ndk-bundle ). TY