# Debugging C++ library with Android Studio

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, java-native-interface, android-studio-3.0

I'm working on an `Android` project which uses a `Java` class that is a wrapper on a `C++` library. The C++ library is a company internal library and we have access to its source code, but in the Android project it is only dynamically linked, so it is used only in the form of headers (*.h*) and shared objects (*.so*). Having access to the library source code, is it possible to specify to Android Studio the path to the source code so I can step inside the library using the debugger?

The debugger works, I can step inside the `Java_clory_engine_sdk_CloryNative_nativeInit` function, but I would also like to further debug the library corresponding to the `Clory::Engine` class which, as I mentioned, is an internal library we have source code access to.

[image: c_clory]

For example, `Clory::Engine::instance` is part of the library and I would like to specify to Android Studio the location of the `CloryEngine.cpp` file so I can step inside `Clory::Engine::instance` with the debugger, thus debugging this static member function.

I am using Android Studio 3.1.4.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

The `clory-sdk.gradle` file specifies the `CMakeLists.txt` file which configures the C++ layer.

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

So I am using an internal application which uses the *Clory SDK*. Inside the `app.gradle` file I use:

```
dependencies {
...
    compile project(':clory-sdk-core')
    compile project(':clory-sdk')
...
}
```

so I don't think we're using the `aar`s for the `app.gradle` project. The `aar`s are shipped to the client, but we are using `app.gradle` project to test our little SDK functionalities before doing that. The JNI layer is inside `clory-sdk-core` project.

**EDIT 2:**

Here is the `CMakeLists.txt` which handles the JNI layer:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)

add_library(
    clory-lib
    SHARED
    # JNI layer and other helper classes for transferring data from Java to Qt/C++
    src/main/cpp/clory-lib.cpp
    src/main/cpp/JObjectHandler.cpp
    src/main/cpp/JObjectResolver.cpp
    src/main/cpp/JObjectCreator.cpp
    src/main/cpp/DataConverter.cpp
    src/main/cpp/JObjectHelper.cpp
    src/main/cpp/JEnvironmentManager.cpp
)

find_library(
    log-lib
    log
)

target_compile_options(clory-lib
    PUBLIC
        -std=c++11
)

# Hardcoded for now...will fix later...
set(_QT_ROOT_PATH /Users/jacob/Qt/5.8)

if(${ANDROID_ABI} MATCHES ^armeabi-v7.*$)
    set(_QT_ARCH android_armv7)
elseif(${ANDROID_ABI} MATCHES ^x86$)
    set(_QT_ARCH android_x86)
else()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Unsupported Android architecture!!!")
endif()

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${_QT_ROOT_PATH}/${_QT_ARCH})

find_package(Qt5 REQUIRED COMPONENTS
    Core
    CONFIG
)

target_include_directories(clory-lib
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main/cpp
)

set(_CLORYSDK_LIB_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/src/main/jniLibs/${ANDROID_ABI})

target_link_libraries(clory-lib
    ${log-lib}
    -L${_CLORYSDK_LIB_PATH}
    clorysdk
    Qt5::Core
)
```

The library `clorysdk` is actually our internal library I was talking about, which contains e.g. `Clory::Engine::instance` I would like to step into with the debugger. It was built with `qmake` and is built in debug mode (`CONFIG+=debug` was added in the effective qmake call).

**EDIT 3:**

In the `LLDB` session which has opened after it hit the `Java_clory_engine_sdk_CloryNative_nativeInit` breakpoint, I got the following:

```
(lldb) image lookup -vrn Clory::Engine::instance
2 matches found in /Users/jacob/.lldb/module_cache/remote-android/.cache/6EDE4F0A-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/libclorysdk.so:
        Address: libclorysdk.so[0x0001bb32] (libclorysdk.so..text + 8250)
        Summary: libclorysdk.so`Clory::Engine::instance(Clory::Engine::Purpose)
         Module: file = "/Users/jacob/.lldb/module_cache/remote-android/.cache/6EDE4F0A-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/libclorysdk.so", arch = "arm"
         Symbol: id = {0x0000005e}, range = [0xcb41eb32-0xcb41ebc0), name="Clory::Engine::instance(Clory::Engine::Purpose)", mangled="_ZN4Clory2Engine8instanceENS0_7PurposeE"
        Address: libclorysdk.so[0x0001b82c] (libclorysdk.so..text + 7476)
        Summary: libclorysdk.so`Clory::Engine::instance(Clory::RuntimeConfiguration const&, Clory::Engine::Purpose)
         Module: file = "/Users/jacob/.lldb/module_cache/remote-android/.cache/6EDE4F0A-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/libclorysdk.so", arch = "arm"
         Symbol: id = {0x000000bd}, range = [0xcb41e82c-0xcb41e970), name="Clory::Engine::instance(Clory::RuntimeConfiguration const&, Clory::Engine::Purpose)", mangled="_ZN4Clory2Engine8instanceERKNS_20RuntimeConfigurationENS0_7PurposeE"

(lldb) settings show target.source-map
target.source-map (path-map) =
```

First of all, there was no `CompileUnit` section in the result of the command `image lookup -vrn Clory::Engine::instance`. How is this possible to have no *source-map* defined(second *lldb* command) if the `libclorysdk.so` was built in *Debug* mode? Is it possible to explicitly set it so that the debugger would search there for the library's source files?

**EDIT 4:**

After searching more I found out that the process of creating the APK actually strips the `*.so` libraries from their debugging symbols. `libclorysdk.so` built in debug mode has about 10MB while the `libclorysdk.so` file which I extracted after unarchiving the generated `*.apk` file is just 350KB.
As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12801855/1007758), running `greadelf --debug-dump=decodedline libclorysdk.so` on the debug version outputs references to the source files, but if the command is run on the `*.apk` extracted library, it outputs nothing.

Is there a way to stop Android Studio from stripping the `*.so`s? I tried [How to avoid stripping for native code symbols for android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355200/how-to-avoid-stripping-for-native-code-symbols-for-android-app/42269046) but didn't have any effect, `*.apk` file is the same size as before and debugging the native libraries still doesn't work.

I'm using `Gradle 3.1.4`.

**EDIT 5:**

The [stripping solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40355200/how-to-avoid-stripping-for-native-code-symbols-for-android-app/42269046) works, but in my case, it needed a Clean & Build before hitting the breakpoints in the library. Deploying `*.so`s which are not stripped is allowing you to have debugging sessions and step inside the native libraries.

***Note:***

*If the libraries are built using the `Qt for Android` toolchain, the `*.so`s deployed to `$SHADOW_BUILD/android-build` are also stripped(where `$SHADOW_BUILD` is the build directory usually starting with `build-*`). So in order to debug those you should copy them from outside the `android-build` directory where each `*.so` is generated.*

Comment: Are you using a debug build of the prebuilt shared library? If so, stepping into code within that library should work.

Comment: @Michael I am using a debug build of the prebuilt shared library. But the source code is not within the project which uses the shared library. So it can't know where to search for the source code (I assume) unless I tell it where to search. And I don't know how to do that. I remember if you want to step inside a library in Visual Studio you get a dialog box that lets you browse for the source file corresponding to the function you're stepping into, like so: https://i.imgur.com/doPgOs4.png
I would expect some sort of functionality that gives you something similar...

Comment: I did a little test myself, and stepping into code within a prebuilt shared library from another project worked fine for me. However, I've only tested this with both projects being built on the same machine. Perhaps the project structure looks different on your machine compared to the machine that build the shared library? You can try running `readelf --string-dump=.debug_str mylib.so` to see where the source files are expected to exist.

Comment: @Michael Thank you very much for the answer. Hmmm...I will build tonight a small project with which I will try to reproduce my scenario on a smaller scale and let you know what I found.

Comment: Do you have `ndk` or `cmake` configuration for your project? Or is the lib you're using packaged as an `aar`?

Comment: @ahasbini Thank you for your answer, I have edited my question to provide the information you're asking for. Please ask if it is not clear, I will provide further information.

Comment: Could you post the `CMakeLists.txt`? As for further clarity and correct me if I'm wrong, your project contains `app` module is a regular app with `plugin: 'com.android.application'` defined in the `app.gradle`. The `clory-sdk-core` and `clory-sdk` are also project modules which have the their `gradle` files containing `plugin: 'com.android.library'` with the only difference is `clory-sdk` containing `CMakeLists.txt` file and C/C++ code.

Comment: @ahasbini Thank you very much for your questions. What you described is exactly the case, with just one exception: `clory-sdk-core` contains `CMakeLists.txt`, and _NOT_ `clory-sdk`. So `clory-sdk-core.gradle` contains `externalNativeBuild {cmake {path "CMakeLists.txt"}}` while `clory-sdk` has `clory-sdk-core` as a dependency: `dependencies {compile project(':glas.ai-sdk-core')`.
I have posted an edit and I added the `CMakeLists.txt` for more clarity.

Comment: I have a test application that uses/tests an apk. This apk library is dependent on a .so file. I want to be able to add breakpoints and debug into the .so file. I built all of the projects in debug mode with the "donot strip" packaging option but still I am not able to step into the library. Can you help?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The debug info records the location of the source files when they were built.

```
(lldb) image lookup -vrn Clory::Engine::instance
```

The CompileUnit line shows the source file. Suppose it says:

```
"/BuildDirectory/Sources/Clory/CloryEngine.cpp"
```

Let's assume you have the source on your machine here:

```
"Users/me/Sources/Clory"
```

So you can tell lldb: find the source file rooted at /BuildDirectory/Sources/Clory in Users/me/Sources/Clory instead.

```
(lldb) settings set target.source-map /BuildDirectory/Sources/Clory Users/me/Sources/Clory
```

You can use these commands in the lldb console of Android Studio or put into a .lldbinit file for general use.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I ran `$ lldb libclorysdk.so` and after that I ran `(lldb) image lookup -vrn Clory::Engine::instance` I get only 4 sections: `Address`, `Summary`, `Module` and `Symbol`. It looks something like this: https://pastebin.com/2wBrD1nJ
Any idea why I don't get the `CompileUnit` information? My libraries are all built in debug mode.

Comment: It seems that the libclorysdk.so has no debug information. Try to rebuild the sdk with debug info or use the debug version of the sdk if it's available. Use these lldb commands in Android Studio. Set a breakpoint in the `Java_clory_engine_sdk_CloryNative_nativeInit` function. Start the debuging. When you stop at the breakpoint use the lldb window of Android Studio to run the lldb commands above.

Answer (score 10):

If there no debug symbols available, you might have to build the referenced library in debug mode.

Either with `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG`:

```
defaultConfig {
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            arguments "-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=gcc", "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=DEBUG"
            cppFlags "-std=c++14 -fexceptions -frtti"
        }
    }
}

externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path file('src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt')
    }
}
```

Or add this to the `CMakeLists.txt` of the library:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)
```

See the [CMake](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-variables.7.html) documentation and [Symbolicating with LLDB](https://lldb.llvm.org/symbolication.html).

[Elsewhere](https://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) it explains `(lldb) settings set target.source-map /buildbot/path /my/path`:

> Remap source file path-names for the debug session. **If your source files are no longer located in the same location as when the program was built** --- maybe the program was built on a different computer --- you need to tell the debugger how to find the sources at their local file path instead of the build system's file path.

There's also `(lldb) settings show target.source-map`, to see what is mapped.
`(lldb) set append target.source-map /buildbot/path /my/path` seems rather suitable, in order not to overwrite existing mappings.

Comment: Thank you so very much for your answer! I added `set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug)` to my `CMakeLists.txt` in my android project which handles the JNI layer. I also made sure that all my libraries are built in Debug mode as the library is built with `CONFIG+=debug`(i'm using `Qt 5.8` with `GCC 4.9` - I don't think it matters tough as, I read, debugging `gcc` compiled code should be possible with `lldb`).
Now I'm new to bridging C++ and Java in Android and I may make stupid mistakes and ask stupid questions. Here's what I'm doing: in the Android Studio terminal I run `$ lldb libclorysdk.so`.

Comment: The problem is that when I run and then `(lldb) settings show target.source-map` I get the following message: `target.source-map (path-map) =`. This means that no path is associated with that variable(I suppose). Now I tried `settings set target.source-map "" /Users/jacob/Work/clory/sdk/native/sdk/base`(_base_ folder is the location of the project which generates my `libclorysdk.so` library i.e. location of the qmake _.pro_ project file) and when I run `(lldb) settings show target.source-map` I get `target.source-map (path-map) = [0] "" -> "/Users/jacob/Work/clory/sdk/native/sdk/base"`.

Comment: In this point I still couldn't enter inside `Clory::Engine::instance` with the debugger. I also tried to set the key(value before "->") to be the path to my `libclorysdk.so`(located inside the android project) and the value(value after "->") to be the path to my _clory_ library sdk source code; so when I ran `(lldb) settings show target.source-map` I get `target.source-map (path-map) = [0] "/Users/jacob/Work/clory/sdk/android/clory-sdk-core/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a" -> "/Users/jacob/Work/clory/sdk/native/sdk/"`.

Comment: At this point when I ran the debugger I still couldn't enter inside `Clory::Engine::instance`. Another i think important thing is that when I exit `lldb` with `(lldb) exit` and I run `$ libclorysdk.so` againe, all the mappings ar gone; so the operations are not persistent. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: When you run `$ lldb libclorysdk.so` you create a separate new lldb session. The command what you type here will be valid for that session. After `(lldb) exit` the session will be closed.
Use lldb console of Android Studio instead of the command line tool as I mentioned at my answer.

Comment: @Peter Thank you again! Please see _Edit 3_ section, where I explained the outcome of what you suggested. Could there be a further solution I could try?

Comment: I got `ERROR: Could not find method arguments() for arguments` after modifying build.gradle.

Comment: @zwcloud you need to add the `arguments` into `defaultConfig > externalNativeBuild > cmake > arguments`... and the path to `CMakeLists.txt` outside of the `defaultConfig`. I've updated my answer to make this more clear.